# Qml/Qt/C++: QQuickView in a Widget, can't get the position right

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qml, qquickview

I'am implementing a simple program with QT5.5 which contains a HTML window (QWebview) like the following screenshot:

[HTML window on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iPGH.png)

Now I want the program also installed for iOS e.g. for iPad. I found that the QWebview class isn't available for mobile system, so I had to change my HTML window to QQuickView with QML files (or is there a better way?). I found the following code online:

```
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);
container->setMinimumSize(200,400);
container->setMaximumSize(200,400);
container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///webview.qml"));
layout->addWidget(container);
```

Then i added the container to the mainWindow.
The webview.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtWebView 1.0
Rectangle {
id: rectangle
width: 200
height: 400
WebView {
    id: webview
    url: "file:///test.html"
    anchors.fill: parent
    width: 200
    height: 400
}
}
```

But somehow I can't get the layout right. 
[HTML window on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeT9L.png)
There is a blank/white rectangle behind the container, and the container is also not in the HTML window on the right side where it should be. When I change the width and the height of the rectangle in the qml file, it only changes the size of the webview, not the white background.

Can anyone tell me, how can I get this right? I have also used `container->setParent()` but the view is always on the left.

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of the author's code is maybe not enough but overall it is easier to set the widget in layout with certain alignment. This way you command the widget to be on certain side and make the placement not to depend on coordinates / host widget size etc. The `layout` variable is assumed to be horizontal box layout or QHBoxLayout.

```
// make sure that QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
// or set the horizontal layout somehow else
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);

container->serFixedWidth(200); // the layout is horizontal
                               // and we *may* want to fix the width

container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///webview.qml"));
layout->addWidget(container, Qt::AlignRight); // align to the right
```

Mind that the rest of *horizontal* layout should be filled like that with respecting relative positions in it.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback because it's Christmas and New year time :). The `layout` in my code was `QVBoxLayout`, but i have tested with both `QHBoxLayout` and `QVBoxLayout` and `Qt::AlignRight`, but it has not changed at all. It's odd because the "html window" is actually there on the right where it should be, but its content not. It seems like the container doesn't have the right parent, but when I output `container->parent()`, it it correct. Do you know where can I be doing wrong?